# KQL Query to Get All Blog Posts

Tags: development, web-part, kql

I am having trouble formatting a KQL statement which returns all Blog Posts from an entire site collection.  Bonus points if I can filter by date posted, to only get newer Blog Posts.  I am unsure if Blog posts would be STS_ListItems or not.

I have been trying to build one, but it has not been successful.

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "spcontenttype:" + SPBuiltInContentTypeId.BlogPost.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blog posts will always have a Content Type Id starting with 0x0110, so this query will show you all blog posts:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "ContentTypeId:0x0110*";
```

And this query will also let you filter by date - in this example, only display blog posts from 2016-01-01:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "ContentTypeId:0x0110* Created>=2016-01-01";
```

By default these queries will return you ALL blog posts, not just those in the site collection. To show all bog posts just for one specific site collection, you also need to add a Path filter with the URL of your site collection, like this:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "ContentTypeId:0x0110* Created>=2016-01-01 Path:http://example.com/sites/site1";
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you! I got Content type and Created working, currently Path is returning nothing when I put in something like                  

`"ContentTypeId:0x0110* Created>2015-07-01 Path:https://myspsite.com/sites/site1/subsite"`

Comment: As in, When I have just ContentTypeId And Created, I get results, but when I add in Path, I then get nothing, even though some of the previous results are under that path.  I tried `"Path:http://url.com/site"` `"Path:/site1/site2"` and `Path="http://url.com/site"`

Comment: You can also try Site managed property, like `Site:https://myspsite.com/sites/site1/subsite`, although Path should definitely work, but I have no idea why it doesn't at the moment

Comment: Spoke with my sysad, found that the development search had not done a full crawl yet.  Things are working as intended, thanks Justas!

Comment: I can now get the blog posts that I need, but am having trouble getting the blog post's Body.  How do I get the Body from these results?

Comment: Try reading BodyOWSMTXT managed property

Comment: That is not being returned in my query, so that throws an error, is there a way to specify in KQL what fields to return with the query?

Comment: Yes, you can add the fields in SelectProperties:
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("BodyOWSMTXT");